# Remove terms in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, something like this:

```
$array = array(
  'hello',
  'world',
  'lorem',
  'ipsum',
  'what',
  'is',
  'reality'
);
```

And I have a string variable:

```
$terms = 'Hello World is reality!';
```

So, if `$array` contains any of the terms in `$terms`, then I want to remove those from the array. So in this case, `$terms` will end up being:

```
$array = array(
  'lorem',
  'ipsum',
  'what'
);
```

What the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: You can filter the array with `array_filter()` and check with `stripos()`, if the term is anywhere in the string.

Comment: @Rizier123 Please post an answer demonstrating how. Please note that I don't want it to be case sensitive and it should ignore special characters. So **World** matches with **world!**

Comment: This is not a code writing service. @Rizier123 is right on the money with the PHP functions you'll need to use. Give it a shot, come back when you have a specific issue and can show the code you have so far.

Comment: Go look up the two functions in the manual, read it, look at the examples, and try to solve the problem with these two functions. If you get stuck, post your attempt.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/wOsEq7N.png

Comment: Also, you need to figure behavior on special chars. I.e. 'facade' == 'façade' or not?

Comment: @fusion3k Yes,  'facade' == 'façade' should match. Do you have an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$terms = 'Hello World is reality!';
$result = array_filter(array_map(function ($word) use ($terms) {
    if (!stristr($terms, $word)) {
       return $word;
    }
},$array));
```

output:

```
array(3) {
  [2] =>
   string(5) "lorem"
  [3] =>
   string(5) "ipsum"
  [4] =>
   string(4) "what"
}
```

Comment: This is outstanding, but it doesn't seem to remove words in this scenario: **john** and **john's**

Comment: Maybe we can work something out using http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Answer (score -2):

You need to explode the string first and make it into an array.

```
$termsArray = explode(" ", $terms);
```

Then simply differentiate it from the first array.

```
$result=array_diff($array,$termsArray);
```

This will return the elements that are not present in the $termsArray.

Comment: Not my downvote. But: 1) what about 'reality!'? 2) What about (i.e.) `$terms = 'Hello World is another day';` ?